# How to send a tall array to a classifier?

Tags: arrays, matlab, bigdata

I am trying to send a `tall array` to the classifier to run, however, i am facing this error:

```
tt=fitcnb(tall(data),tall(label));
Error using tall/fitcnb (line 39)
Incompatible tall array arguments. The tall arrays must be based on the same datastore.
```

Could someone give me some hints how to tackle this error? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `tall` arrays in MATLAB, the constructor that you're using is really intended only for prototyping - ultimately, it is expected that you will derive your `tall` arrays from a `datastore`, and for `fitcnb` to work correctly, the inputs must derive from the same `datastore` to ensure they are compatible (the error message is somewhat misleading in this case - the `tall` arrays are not compatible because they were created with separate invocations of the constructor).

That being said, you can make this prototype version work by creating a single `tall` `table` and using that with `fitcnb`:

```
% Get some data for fitcnb
load fisheriris
X = meas(:,3:4);
Y = species;
% Make a single tall table
data = tall(table(X, Y));
% Run 'fitcnb'
fitcnb(data.X, data.Y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I could run it now. I really appreciate your help. I have one more question. Is there any way that I can run my big data which has been saved in tall array with `RUSBoost` classifier? It seems this classifier is not supported by tall array. What can I do? What do you suggest? Thanks a lot